# OpServer Performance very slow, no auto refresh

Tags: sql-server, opserver

I installed OpServer on an virtual Server running Windows Server 2012 R2 with 2.5GB of RAM. I configured the `SQLSettings.json` to monitor the SQL Server cluster (SQL Server 2014 SP1). The cluster has three nodes at the moment with about 200 databases, more or less equally distributed.

The server, on which OpServer runs, is not busy with anything. The SQL Servers are also very relaxed.

Installation was "a snap". Configuration as well..

But now i have the issue, that the "main screen" does not refresh itself, even with `"refreshIntervalSeconds": 20` in the SQL config file. 
I tried to change the configuration, so that only the instances of the three SQL Servers are shown, but that does not change the time it takes to manually refresh.

If I press "refresh" it takes about 23 seconds until the screen is shown again.

Then, why does OpServer not refresh automatically? Do I need to configure something more??

If I run it locally on my PC, configured to some other SQL Server database servers, the refresh works and the manual refresh is quite fast. I cant test it with the same cluster servers on my local machine due to some multi domain configuration and firewall settings, which are not in my responsibility...

Does any one have an idea why I don't get an automatic refresh and why the manual refresh takes so long?

Thanks

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this, as I found the same issue!

Comment: In the web.config file, search for the word `debug` and change from `debug="true"` to `debug="false"`. This worked for me!